# Svelte-i18n complains of unexpected token at colon in json file

Tags: javascript, json, svelte

I have been working with Svelte using Routify and Svelte-i18n. I cannot seem to get Svelte-i18n to run at all.

I have the following i18n file:

```json
{
  "header.title": "Title"
}
```

It is imported in `i18n.js` here:

```js
import { addMessages, init, getLocaleFromNavigator } from "svelte-i18n";
import en from "./locales/en.json";

addMessages("en", en);

init({
  fallbackLocale: "en",
  initialLocale: getLocaleFromNavigator(),
});
```

And initialized in `App.svelte` like so:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { Router } from "@roxi/routify";
  import { routes } from "../.routify/routes";

  import "./i18n";
</script>

<Router {routes} />

<style global>
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis|Great+Vibes&display=swap");
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
</style>
```

But no matter what, I keep getting `unexpected token` on the colon within the json file. I have no idea why this is happening, given this is a properly formatted json file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue would likely be that you have not added a json parser.

```
$ npm i @rollup/plugin-json
```

or

```
yarn add @rollup/plugin-json
```

Then import it in `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
```

Then add it somewhere within the plugin section:

```js
json()
```

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you need to change "header.title" to "header_title". If you use "header.title" you should have it like this in your HTML/svelte file

```html
<h1>{$_('header.title')}</h1>
```

and like this in your `en.json`

```json
{
  "header": {
    "title": "Hello"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue at hand. The issue was that the json file is not being parsed at all. My answer deals with the parsing of json. However you do have a point on the name mismatch and would ultimately need to be fixed regardless. But this was not what was causing the parsing issue.